# How to create a stand alone spring boot based java library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot based microservice and in order to make sure that the code is reusable, methods which this microservices uses are built into a separate java library. This java library is a separate repository.

Till now this java library was a pure java library and simply including the library in `pom.xml` of the spring boot app everything worked fine. But now I am converting this library  into a spring boot based library. So I modified the `pom.xml` of library by including the standard spring boot dependency. The methods are now converted to Beans by using `@Component` annotation.

Now in the main spring boot app when I am trying to use autowire and create the bean of the class in a java library my application is not coming up by throwing the error that the specified bean does not exist

I am not sure what would have caused this. I did lots of google search but could not find any useful information for creating a separate spring boot based library and integrating it into a spring boot app.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve such problem.

1. You can instantiate `Bean` from external library by simply doing `ComponentScan` in you spring boot application for the least package in that JAR.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.your.path.to.least.pkg")
public class ExternalJarConfig {
//no code needed here, beans will be scanned from jar from com.your.path.to.least.pkg package
}
```

2. In case your library has requirement to work like other spring boot starters then you can create custom spring boot starter.
   See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter) tutorial and [this](https://github.com/RobustBase/auth-token-propagator) repository.

Comment: Thanks Atul.. I think  for me the first approach should work... Can you please elaborate a little more by explaining what would this class ExternalConfig  would contain

Comment: No code needed in that class, it's only to tell spring, go in JAR in com.your.path.to.least.pkg package, scan all spring beans, construct the object and inject whereever those are need (in you case autowire).

Comment: If this solution works for you, then you can accept the answer so that I can help others too.

Comment: Thanlks Atul.This works!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The beans are probably not found because the packages of your library and your main application are different. You would need to specify where to scan for components:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.common.base.package")
```

I would suggest to read through section [Creating Your Own Auto-configuration in the official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration) on how to build Spring starter dependencies and at the [Master Spring Boot auto-configuration demo repository on Github](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot-master-auto-configuration). This will provide further details on how to smoothly integrate dependencies with Spring Boot mechanisms.